# Toast Notification Fails, Simulator

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am using the toast notification sample here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-notifications-sample-52eeba29

The toast notifications appear when I select local machine for testing. When I select simulator, all I see is XML. My manifest has toast enabled. Am I missing any steps?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toast notifications (and other APIs, including those related to tile updates and push notifications) do not work in the simulator.  For testing and debugging, use "Local Machine" as the deployment target.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it is in one of the notes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx