# How to go to lock screen windows 8 simulator?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, lockscreen

I'm trying to develop a small application that uses the lock screen notification.

I'm running the Windows 8 Simulator and I'm trying to go to the lock screen with no success.

Help anybody?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571931/1656796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the lock screen and notifications APIs (toast, tile, and badge) do not work in the Windows 8 Simulator.  To test and debug, use "Local Machine" as the target.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut for lock is Windows key + L.  Try that in the simulator.

Comment: It will lock your machine, not the simulator. :(

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to run remote desktop from my laptop and connect to my desktop machine.  On the desktop the actual monitor will show the current lockscreen.  Then from my remote desktop session I could use my app and watch the real lockscreen from the main monitor.

It was sort of a hack, but it worked.  My lockscreen app changes the image, so being able to see it easily made a huge difference to me.